# How to save the contact from who I received an SMS?

Tags: iphone, contacts, sms

I received an SMS from a phone nr that I don't have saved in my iPhone. How do I save that number as a new contact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Scroll to the top of the thread in Messages
- Tap on "Contact" (button at top right)
- Create new contact